# Is it possible to keep admin persistence in an application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, admin, elevated-privileges

I want to write a small function which will keep admin persistence in my application. So even after the computer is restarted the application will still have admin privileges. Is this possible to do? Also, if I disable the UAC, will it be re-enabled on reboot?

Comment: I don't recommend disabling UAC. That's a rather extreme system-wide change for the sake of your one program.

Comment: What else can you recommend doing if I am looking to get my program to start-up without having the "open file warning" appear on reboot?

Comment: Brady's answer is good, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling UAC in Windows, on your account, will not cause it to be re-enabled on reboot.

Not sure if this helps but if you right click the application and choose "Properties" and then the "Compatibility" tab there's an option you can check to make sure the program always open with admin privileges.

Comment: Oh really! Hmm, perfect. And if I disable the UAC, will the "would you like to run or cancel this file" window come up on startup? And what if I re-enable UAC after the application is started?